# set spacing in table with paragraph column

Tags: tables

I struggle to set the spacing in a table when a row has multiple lines due to a paragraph column. I already reduced the distance between rows, but this is about the spacing within one row.Here is the short form of my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
\caption{Summary Statistics: Continuous Variables   \label{sumstat}}
{ 
\begin{tabular}{l p{7cm} c c c c  }
\cline{1-2}
\toprule
 &         &          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Within}&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Between}\\  \cline{3-4} \cline{5-6} \noalign{\smallskip}
Variable    &  Description   &          Mean&  SD&          Mean&  SD\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textit{Dependent Variables}} \\
TreatWin       & 1 if household installed new windows in the last year and subsequently, 0 otherwise   &       x&                 x &  x&                 x\\
envir       &       concerned about the environmental protection, categorical from 0 (not at all) to 2 (very)&       x&                 x &  x&                 x\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Thank you for your help!

Best, Fabian

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, exactly:  the rows are too close from each other? This makes the table hard to read.

Comment: setting arraystretch to less than 1 makes it impossible to get consistent spacing, but the larger spacing you are getting in the p column is the normal line spacing that you get for that font in the rest of the document, do you really want to keep the font size but reduce the linespace just in the table???

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Yes, I want to reduce the line spacing, so reducing the space between "1 if the household installed new windows in"  and "the last year and subsequently, 0 otherwise"